# Looking for the best way to make a web framework more OO on the server side

Tags: java, hibernate, javabeans, pojo, oop

Web frameworks seem to always wander away from good OO code (Where you group code and data together in an object, think in terms of sending messages to that object, etc)

The main problem seems to be the existence of the bean pattern.  You use a bean pattern (often called POJOs these days because people don't seem to understand the difference) to interact with the database, web services and most other things.

So no you are stuck with this ball of setters and getters with no code--so you tend to add a bunch of--well essentially static functions to manipulate these things.  Nearly all the advantages of OO code are gone.

I see three solutions I'm considering, but wanted to hear if there were any serious disadvantages to any of them.

1) use a POJO pattern instead of a bean pattern.  This would mean eliminating setters and getters from your POJOs (so you can have encapsulation/data safety) and instead adding business logic methods.  This seems to make the most sense--in fact I think it's why libraries like hibernate switched away from requiring Beans to allowing POJOs, yet everyone still seems to use a bean pattern instead.

2) extend your Bean with a business logic class that uses the bean's fields as storage.  This seems flakey and problematic, but would be very easy to drop into an existing codebase as a way to migrate...

3) Wrap a Bean pattern object with a business-logic object.  Mostly I think this might be necessary if #1 is really problematic.

What I'm mostly wondering is why I've never seen #1 used.  I'd really love to hear from anyone who used the Pojo pattern (With business logic and without setters and getters) for hibernate objects and had problems with it (or had it work really well)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good reasons to keep (most of) business logic outside the data objects, but optimal design will include certain parts of it there. This is not exactly easy to get right, especially in a blue-collar team setting, which is I guess 95% of all Java dev teams out there.

I like to put some simple, self-contained, widely reusable pieces of logic into my data objects; code that is inherently coupled to that data without regard to any specific business request. Examples would be some conversions, validations, etc.

As far as getters and setters, I avoid them at all costs. You could use public final fields, or just plain public fields. The getter+setter combo gives you exactly as much encapsulation as a public field: zero.

As far as ORM solutions, I use Hibernate strictly as a convenience over SQL, and never as a persistent state manager. The mapped classes are there only as a replacement for XML mapping; they are never even instantiated in read operations. For inserts I save each object individually, which maps one-to-one with a single database row, without transitive persistence. This basically means that my Hibernate model objects are just a Java way of looking at database rows (plus the convenient join column specifications—HQL looks much nicer without those redundant join criteria).

Comment: I really like the first paragraph here.  I'm not crazy about exposing properties directly any more than accessor methods though, they both encourage people to ask data from your object rather than ask your object to do something for you (A good way to tell if you are writing good OO code...), but really good points.

Comment: In an earlier project I tried to make a "muscular" domain model that encompassed all business logic in it. The objects were ORM-mapped. The result was a terrible mess, with subtle bugs being manifested years after deployment. Also, most business-logic actions are not tied to only one entity, so it doesn't make sense to put them into entity objects.

Comment: I also found out the hard way that ORM doesn't pay. Nothing will shield you from the SQL---and nothing **should**, really. If you want performance, your only hope is custom SQL (or HQL) for each and every business service separately, fetching exactly the amount of data needed, and all of it in a single fetch (if at all possible).

Comment: Excellent comments, thank you--exactly what I was looking for!  I think your advice about putting only light highly object-related stuff into the domain is good too (Most code I've seen doesn't even do that--it tends to follow the bean pattern exactly).  Just out of curiosity, what kind of bugs were caused by the "muscular" domain model?

Comment: An important point was actually mentioned in one of the other answers---the methods that look like plain getters from the outside actually performed additional DB queries on the inside. The worst problem I mentioned was where a calculation was lazily performed only upon access of each collection member, for that member. It took 5 years of continuous usage before it first occurred that an item wasn't visible in the GUI list until the user scrolled to it, and then it broke because the DB session was already closed at that time.

Comment: About the bean pattern---people will counter my approach with "but a setter may perform additional validation" or similar. That is a **lie**. Nobody dares touch the logic of the setter since everyone expects pure write-through and whatever else you put in there, someone, somewhere may want to set the field *without* that extra logic performed, and then your "smart setter" is reduced to nothing but a bug.

Comment: I agree.  I think that using final public variables is better than getters any day--I'm not so sure about writable variables (OR Setters!)  I like to make my classes "Safe" so that they can't be put into an illegal state externally--how do you do that when you expose your internals.  The builder pattern helps too--write to the variables initially then "Seal" the class so the setters can't be called again.

Comment: A typical bean has no internal state at all---every property is independently settable. There are many real-life situations where you need nothing more than a C-style `struct`. Of course, whenever you are designing a "real" object, with actual behavior distinct from the union of its state variables, you will definitely use `private` vars. But that's an entirely separate subject.

Comment: Properties (variables) are state...  Beans are nothing but state.  Pure data objects like you are saying do exist (Name, address, etc)--but if you are REALLY just data, why the heck isn't it a hash?  Making an object for storing stuff that has no code related to it is just wrong (One of the big shortcomings of Java I think is that it doesn't have type-safe hashes which is why people make beans).  Of course, annotating those fields makes a great place to put configuration and is the one redeeming thing about data objects-but as you said why not just make them public variables?

Comment: You are dead-on with the point about hashes. I absolutely hate the amount of boilerplate I need to write every time I need nothing but a hash. Truth be told, a typesafe hash is not an option in any language, but who said I want type safety in every case? If the distance between declaration and use of a structure is short, static typing adds very little to safety anyway. If Java didn't insist on explicit downcasts, I'd probably use hashes. BTW maybe you know this, but modern frameworks are indeed moving towards public vars. Hibernate 4 puts them on an equal footing with classic beans.

Answer (score 3):

I'll change my comment into an answer.  I basically disagree with your opening premise

> Web frameworks seem to always wander away from good OO code.

Nothing in Java EE or a Spring/JPA model "wander[s] away from good OO code".  That fact that a JPA provider like hibernate allows POJOs doesn't mean that you can't use a rich domain model, that defines the business logic in the beans.  For Java web apps, I have seen it done both ways -- rich domain model, or an anemic domain model with the business logic in the service layer, which isn't necessary non-OO or a bad design.

I think maybe what you meant to say is a lot of apps are not written with proper design and/or proper OO.  **That** I will agree with.  But that has nothing to do with the frameworks....

So your proposed solutions all basically say "properly design your application with good OO principles". Option 1 is the simplest.

Comment: You are right, I totally phrased that wrong. What I mean is that the practices I've seen used when someone uses typical web frameworks (including beans and the fact that event handlers tend to be functions instead of methods). It's not that you can't write good OO, it's just that most places I've worked, people who would have otherwise written in an OO style simply didn't--and mostly because you had to get and set from the "beans" rather than just asking the bean to do something for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused on what exactly you are arguing here, as you say both that people tend to call beans "POJOs" then you suggest that instead of using beans you use "POJO". But to respond to this point:

> So no you are stuck with this ball of setters and getters with no code--so you tend to add a bunch of--well essentially static functions to manipulate these things. Nearly all the advantages of OO code are gone.

I disagree with this - if you are writing static functions to manipulate your objects, something with your design is wrong.

Typically the common/"best" practice is that you wrap your business logic in a "service layer" of classes that knows how to manipulate the data (represented in your beans, POJOs, domain objects, whatever you want to call them) in response to the rules of the application.

No one is stopping you from having your "service layer" be OO-designed, with subclasses and inheritance and all that.

Typically, you won't see someone build an application where the `Employee` class that holds the data also contains methods and logic that perform operations on the `Employee`, as people tend to want to separate the data (represented by the `Employee` class) from the logic. And also practically speaking, once you start having methods that operate on the employee instances in the `Employee` class, then you need to have the `Employee` class be capable of calling into the storage layer itself, and now the class that you use Hibernate to represent the results of queries (the `Employee` class) also has references to Hibernate code to load itself, and it becomes a giant mess.

I think that the "problems" you see are just disagreements you have with the design ideas that are common with these types of applications. Most people want to separate how the data is represented from the code encapsulating the logic of the application.

Comment: Combining code and data is pretty much the definition of OO so yes, your last paragraph sums it up quite nicely.  The problems I see is that I disagree--I happen to like OO code and would like to re-introduce it into these situations by recombining the code and data.

Comment: Well maybe I was too strong on that last point. I think it often makes sense to combine the logic and data, but in something like a webapp with multiple layers, you want to be careful that the OO parts of your design aren't also concerned with things like "how to persist this object" or "how to retrieve my data" - that's where things become too hairy.

Answer (score 0):

Per best practice, the **business logic should be separate from presentation logic**. Most of the web frameworks provide nice features around presentation of the data. Any business logic involved in data retrieval/manipulation should be written in `Business Layer`, which is an additional layer between the `presentation layer` and `data layer`. `POJO` object behave as data carrier between `Business Layer` and `Presentation Layer`. `POJO` are really good candidate for this because they are very light object having attributes as accessor methods.

Rest is up to you. If you want to use complex bean objects with business logic in them, I don't think that any web frameworks stops you from doing that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"What I'm mostly wondering is why I've never seen #1 used." Separation of concerns, the single responsibility principle (probably most of all), testability, etc. The model of "everything is coupled to everything" is convenient, but objectively terrible. (This is not saying that convenient API surfaces are bad, but they should be built OVER well-factored, testable code, not instead of it.)

For instance, when you add a "dumb" DTO layer over your business logic layer, where every view is mapped to a bean that contains everything needed to create the view, you get rid of problems like having to keep a session open to fetch associated properties, or wrangling the ORM into fetching them eagerly. (The former also implies having the N+1 selects problem which increases database roundtrips.)

It also makes keeping track of transaction scope easier if every request is served by a single method call on a dedicated service layer. This call is then a single logical operation over the data, which makes setting up transaction handling trivial.

Last but not least this approach leads to small classes that are easier to understand and change on their own. E.g. if you need to change the algorithm for calculating grade point averages you start in `GradePointAverageCalculator` and navigating from there, instead of the scope of code you need to look at being "`Student.java`, lines 1340 through 1486, then 1502 through 1689, …"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could look into the Model-View-View Model design pattern used by amongst other Knockout (a javascript framework). Here the View Model is introduced as a layer between the Model and View, giving the posibility of separating the view from the model.

Read more about it here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html
..and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel